# C++ Using template with struct in .h file , get unknow error

Tags: c++, templates

Tried to make custom ArrayList , 
the first error told me to add Type Tamplate () to  struct ListNode.

But after follow an error instruction , got new error instead.

" Symbols not found for architecture x86_64

```
 #ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
 #define LINKEDLIST_H

 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
  using namespace std;

 template<typename T>
 struct ListNode<T>{
       T value;
       ListNode<T>* next;

       ListNode(T d,ListNode<T> *n){
       value = d;
       next = n;
     }
 };


 template<typename T>
 class LinkedList
 {
 public :
     LinkedList();
     LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& another);
      ~LinkedList();
     void copy(const LinkedList<T>& another);
     void add(T value);

     void remove(int index);

     int get(int index) const;

     bool isEmpty() const;
     int size() const;
     string toString() const;
     void clear();
     LinkedList<T>& operator = (const LinkedList<T>& another);

 private :
     ListNode<T>* x_front;
     int x_size;
 };

 #endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

.CPP

```
 #include "linkedlist.h"
 #include "strlib.h"
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 template<typename T>
 LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
       x_front = NULL;
       x_size =0;
 }

 template<typename T>
 LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){
     clear();
 }

 template<typename T>
 LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator = (const LinkedList<T>& another){
     delete x_front;
     copy(another);
     return *this;
 }

 template<typename T>
 void LinkedList<T>::copy(const LinkedList<T>& another){
      ListNode<T>* anotherCurrent = another.x_front;

      while(anotherCurrent!=NULL){

          this->add(anotherCurrent->value);
          anotherCurrent = anotherCurrent->next;
       }

 }

 template<typename T>
 void LinkedList<T>::add(T value){
     if(x_front == NULL){
         x_front = new ListNode<T>(value,NULL);
     }
     else {
         ListNode<T>*current = x_front;
         while(current-> next != NULL){
             current = current -> next;
         }
         current->next = new ListNode<T>(value,NULL);
     }
     x_size++;
 }

 template<typename T>
 void LinkedList<T>::remove(int index){

     if(index==0){
         x_front = x_front->next;
     }


 else  {
           ListNode<T>* current = x_front;
           for(int indexNow = 0 ; indexNow < index -1 ; indexNow++){
                                            current = current->next;
           }
           current -> next = current -> next -> next;
    }
    x_size--;
}


template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() const {
    if(this->x_size == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){
    while(this->isEmpty() ==false){
        remove(x_size-1);
    }
}

template<typename T>
string LinkedList<T>::toString() const{
    string mystring;
    for(ListNode<T>*p = x_front; p!=NULL ;p = p->next){

        mystring = mystring + " " + integerToString(p->value);
    }
    return mystring;
}

template<typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::size() const{
      return (this->x_size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your template must be defined inside the header file